# No “Performance” option in “Power Mode” in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: power-management, performance, settings, system-settings, 21.04

I have Ubuntu 21.04 installed on my laptop. There is supposed to be a “Performance” option in Settings > Power Mode, but I am only given the options for “Balanced Power” and “Power Saver”, regardless of whether I am plugged in or not. How can I get the “Performance” option to show up?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. If these options are managed by [GNOME power-profiles-daemon](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/power-profiles-daemon) it could be because our hardware isn't supported.

To quote the link above

> There are 3 different power profiles, a "balanced" default mode,
> a "power-saver" mode, as well as a "performance" mode. The first 2 of those are
> available on every system. The "performance" mode is only available on select
> systems and is implemented by different "drivers" based on the system or
> systems it targets.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Post](https://fostips.com/changing-power-mode-easy-ubuntu-21-04/) you should be able to do that with the [Slimbook Battery Tool](https://launchpad.net/%7Eslimbook/+archive/ubuntu/slimbook).

To install it you need to first add the apt-repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slimbook/slimbook && sudo apt update
```

Then You should be able to install it with:

```
sudo apt install slimbookbattery
```

That fixed this issue for me.